# Getting Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts

Tags: puppet

I am having a solo setup where both master and agent are installed on a single node. While trying to connecting the master i am getting this error.

```
$ bundle exec puppet agent --test --server xxxxxxx   
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:   
Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find terminus console for indirection node  
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts  
Info: Retrieving plugin  
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts  
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog  
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I installed puppet frm source code (Puppet version-4.1,ruby-2.1), but while connecting to the server i am getting this issue.

Please find the puppet.conf below

```
# Settings in [main] are used if a more specific section doesn't set a value.
[main]
    certname = puppet-vm
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    basemodulepath = /home/ppc/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/modules
    server = puppet-vm
    user  = puppet
    group = puppet
    archive_files = true
#   archive_file_server = puppet.example.com
    pluginsync = true

# This section is used by the Puppet master and Puppet cert applications.
[master]
    certname = puppet-vm
    dns_alt_names = puppet-vm,puppetmaster01,puppetmaster01.example.com,puppet,puppet.example.com
    ca_name = 'Puppet CA generated on puppetmaster01.example.com at 2013-08-09 19:11:11 +0000'
#   reporturl = https://localhost:443/reports/upload
    node_terminus = console
    reports = none
#   external_nodes = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet-dashboard/external_node
    ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
    ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
    storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
    storeconfigs = false
    autosign = true

# This section is used by the Puppet agent application.
[agent]
    report = true
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    graph = true
    pluginsync = true
    environment = production
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your `puppet.conf`? Find it using `puppet master --configprint config`.

Comment: Documentation is less than clear. `node_terminus=console` seems to be [PE specific](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html#a-note-about-nodeterminus-for-puppet-enterprise-users). Are you even using external nodes? If not, comment out the `node_terminus` line as well. The error related to facts stumps me. What is the output of `puppet master --configprint facts_terminus`?

Comment: thanks man  worked like a charm...!!!